# Python extracting the Heading of a table in html

Tags: python

I have a very big webpage with a table. I am going to extract table using pandas. I am having difficulty in extracting the title.

```
  <div class="col"> <p>State Name: <span class="badge badge-info1">S01-Class 8</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; PC Name: <span class="badge badge-info1">1-John </span></p> <div class="clearfix">
```

How can I extract only `S01-Class 8` and `1-John`? My table follows this class.

Comment: you could use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to get info from markup.

Comment: Also try `lxml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out `lxml`:

```
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring(html_text)
eles = tree.xpath('//span[@class="badge badge-info1"]')

for e in eles:
    print(e.text) # S01-Class 8, 1-John
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `lxml` (just a matter of taste, some people prefer beautiful soup) and xpath to do it:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(html)
nodes = tree.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'badge-info1')]")
for node in nodes:
    print(node.text)
```

Comment: You have a typo: xpath is unclosed.

Comment: @knh190 Aha! Thanks.